# Laravel Excel Estructura (Importando Fichero)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, excel

Estoy utilizando la librería **Laravel Excel** y me he estado leyendo la documentación pero no dice nada para hacer leer el excel a partir de cierto numero de fila, es decir, tengo las 6 primeras líneas del excel con información y el "titulo" de cada columna no esta hasta la fila 7, como le indico a la función que los "indices" están ahí?

```
public function excel($id){
  $bankFiles = FicheroBanco::find($id);
  $url = $bankFiles->url;

    Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($url, function ($sheet){
        //$sheet->noHeading();
        $sheet->each(function ($row){
            $mov = new Transaccion();
            $mov->cuenta = $row->cuenta;
            $mov->divisa = $row->divisa;
            $mov->titular = $row->titular;
            $mov->fecha = $row->fecha;
            $mov->concepto = $row->concepto;
            $mov->valor = $row->valor;
            $mov->importe = $row->importe;
            $mov->saldo = $row->saldo;
            $mov->observaciones = $row->observaciones;
            $mov->extra = $row->extra;
            $mov->save();
        });
    });
return view('bank.excel');
}
```

He visto que puedo usar el **->take();** para coger las x primeras lineas de un documento o el **->skip();** para saltarme las x primeras líneas. **El problema es que la primera linea del fichero excel es una celda fusionada de 7 columnas no puedo usar los títulos de la linea 6, ya que me monta el array desestructurado.**

**EDITO:** Por defecto se puede configurar desde dentro del archivo de configuración **excel.php** en el campo **'startRow' => 1** pero la cosa es que así tampoco puedo coger ningún tipo de información de los campos anteriores a dicha línea. La cosa es que necesito la info de algunos campos de las 6 primeras líneas, pero necesito indicar que los **headings** empiezan a la línea 6. Alguna idea?

He leído en la documentación que se puede usar el parámetro **->byConfig();** pero según indica solo en caso de no usar headings.

Alguien sabría indicarme como hacerlo?

Necesito insertar en base de datos los campos anteriores a los "títulos" (headings), por cada fila de datos posteriores.

**EDITO:** He estado haciendo pruebas y aunque haga dos funciones diferentes una sin usar headings y la otra si, al haber cambiado el parámetro **startRow** de la configuración tanto uno como otro me cargan desde la misma fila. No sé como indicar a uno que cargue de una fila y el otro cargue desde el principio. Se puede?

**El código de arriba me funciona perfectamente si pongo 'startRow' => 6**, en cambio si uso **noheadings** (con startrow 6) no puedo acceder a filas anteriores del fichero excel.

No puedo modificar la estructura del excel ya que debo ceñirme a ella.

Dejo la documentación -> http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución ha sido, dejar la configuración **excel.php** como estaba, es decir, **'startRow' => 1** para poder acceder a todas las tuplas desde el principio y he hecho lo siguiente:

```
public function excel($id)
    {
        $bankFiles = FicheroBanco::find($id);

        $url = $bankFiles->url;
        $code = $bankFiles->id_banco;

        Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($url, function ($sheet) use($code){
            $sheet->noHeading();

            $results = $sheet->toArray();

            $account = $results[1][1];
            $currency = $results[2][1];
            $owner = $results[3][1];
            $range = $results[4][1];

            $sheet->skip(6);

            $sheet->each(function ($row) use($code, $account, $currency, $owner, $range){

                $fechaOperacion = str_replace('/','-', $row[0]);
                $fechaOperacion = Carbon::parse($fechaOperacion)->format('Y-m-d');

                $fechaValor = str_replace('/','-', $row[2]);
                $fechaValor = Carbon::parse($fechaValor)->format('Y-m-d');

                $mov = new Transaction();
                $mov->id_banco = $code;
                $mov->cuenta = $account;
                $mov->divisa = $currency;
                $mov->titular = $owner;
                $mov->rango = $range;
                $mov->fechaOperacion = $fechaOperacion;
                $mov->concepto = $row[1];                    
                $mov->fechaValor = $fechaValor;
                $mov->importe = $row[3];
                $mov->saldo = $row[4];

                $mov->save();
            });
        });

    }
```

De esta manera he podido sacar lo que quería. El problema era que no sabia como recorrer **$hoja** pero después en la documentación he visto que hay **->toArray()** y **->toObject()** y de esa manera te devuelve el objeto como toca sin posiciones extrañas y for each de toda la vida o lo que haga falta.

Espero que sea útil para alguien.